# Solidity Compile Error: Expected Primary Expression with tokenId counters

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I am trying to write an ERC721 contract that tracks and iterates tokenId using counters.sol from Openzepplin, so that I can manually change the tokenURI to store data on chain. Here is the code throwing an error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
// import ..... (multiple imports)

contract ContractName is ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, ReentrancyGuard, Ownable {

   function FuncName(string memory _top, string memory _content, string memory _bottom) public nonReentrant payable returns (string memory) {

      using Counters for Counters.Counter;
      Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
```

And from this I get the following error:

[image: CompileError: ParserError: Expected primary expression at using]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare

```
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
```

inside the contract, not inside the function FuncName.
Should look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
// import ..... (multiple imports)

contract ContractName is ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, ReentrancyGuard, Ownable {
      using Counters for Counters.Counter;
      Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

   function FuncName(string memory _top, string memory _content, string memory _bottom) public nonReentrant payable returns (string memory) {
```

Hope this helps